# Azure Redis Session State error Timeout performing EVAL, inst:1 , queue:2

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

We are using azure redis cache and was working fine until today where we faced the issue below.

*Timeout performing GET {key}, inst: 1, queue: 2, qu=0, qs=2, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0'*

[image]

Could someone please help me understand:

1. What is causing it?
2. How to solve and stop from happening?