# azure redis Timeout performing EVAL

Tags: azure, stackexchange.redis

Recently we switch to asp.net redis session provider. Since then we keep getting the error below:

> Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 6,
>   qu: 0, qs: 6, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP:
>   (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=4,Max=32767), clientName: PC63020

Yes I did ask the same question here

[Azure Redis Session State error Timeout performing EVAL, inst:1 , queue:2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141453/azure-redis-session-state-error-timeout-performing-eval-inst1-queue2)

But the still hasn't been resolved. I changed premium redis with 6BG Cache.

Is Redis buggy or is there specific settting we need to provide this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration

Consider changing value of connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds, operationTimeoutInMilliseconds, retryTimeoutInMilliseconds according to application needs.

Is you APP and Redis Cache are in same region? if not then you might need larger timeout values. Also if you can share your session state configuration and other information I can help you more.